# Code Execute First Before the data is Fetching in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a condition where I fetch data from API which take 8 seconds to respond in the first use effect and in the second use effect I want to use that data but the problem is that code executes first before the data is fetching and I don't have data in the second use effect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Bluecard from "../../components/bluecard/Bluecard";
import Linechart from "../../charts/linechart/Linechart";
import Solar_1 from "../../assets/images/Solar_1.png";
import Solar_2 from "../../assets/images/Solar_2.png";
import Solar_3 from "../../assets/images/Solar_3.png";
import Solar_4 from "../../assets/images/Solar_4.png";
import Solar_5 from "../../assets/images/Solar_5.png";
import Solar_6 from "../../assets/images/Solar_6.png";
import Solar_7 from "../../assets/images/Solar_7.png";
import Solar_8 from "../../assets/images/Solar_8.png";

function Solarcopy() {
    // ================ First Blue Card Data =======================//
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [blueCardData, setBlueCardData] = useState([]);
    const [lineData, setLineData] = useState({
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [
        {
        label: "Users Gained",
        data: [10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 30],
        backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            "#ecf0f1",
            "#50AF95",
            "#f3ba2f",
            "#2a71d0",
        ],
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 2,
        fill: true,
        },
    ],
    });
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   const fetchdata = async () => {
    //     const response = await fetch("http://192.168.18.21:8000/performance/solar-overview/")
    //     .then((response)=>{
    //       if (!response.ok) {throw new Error("Error in fetching");} 
    //       else {return response.json;}
    //     })
    //     console.log(response)
    //   };
    // }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
    let dataValues = fetch(
        "http://192.168.18.21:8000/performance/solar-overview/"
    )
        .then((dataValues) => dataValues.json())
        .then((dataValues) => {
        // console.log(dataValues)
        setBlueCardData(dataValues);
        setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);
    // ================ First Blue Card Data =======================//

    // ================ First Linechart Data =======================//
    useEffect(() => {
    const arr3 = [];
    const arr4 = [];
    if (!isLoading) {
        blueCardData.pr_hourly.time.map((item) => {
        arr4.push(item.time);
        });
        blueCardData.pr_hourly.pr_hourly.map((item) => {
        arr4.push(item.pr_hourly);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("API Data Loading");
        console.log(arr3);
        setIsLoading(true);
    }

    // fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_limit=5")
    //   .then((response) => response.json())
    //   .then((json) => {
    // arr3 = blueCardData.pr_hourly.time;
    // console.log(arr3)
    // blueCardData.pr_hourly.pr_hourly.map((item) => {
    //   arr4.push(item.pr_hourly);
    // });

    setLineData({
        labels: arr3,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "Values",
            data: arr4,
            backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            "#ecf0f1",
            "#50AF95",
            "#f3ba2f",
            "#2a71d0",
            ],
            borderColor: "black",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fill: true,
        },
        ],
    });
    //   });
    }, []);
    // ================ First Linechart Data =======================//
    // ================== API Response Validation ====================//
    if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading Data</p>;
    }
    // ================== API Response Validation ====================//
    return (
    <>
        <section>
        <Container fluid>
            <Row>
            <Col lg={6}>
                <Row>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.today_revenue}
                    spanText={"PKR"}
                    text={"Today's Revenue"}
                    image={Solar_1}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.cuf}
                    spanText={"%"}
                    text={"CUF"}
                    image={Solar_2}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.total_yield}
                    spanText={"KWH"}
                    text={"Today's Yield"}
                    image={Solar_3}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.cuf}
                    spanText={"%"}
                    text={"CUF"}
                    image={Solar_4}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.system_size}
                    spanText={"kW"}
                    text={"System Size"}
                    image={Solar_5}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.inverters}
                    spanText={""}
                    text={"Number Of Inverters"}
                    image={Solar_6}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.performance_ratio}
                    spanText={"%"}
                    text={"Performance Ratio"}
                    image={Solar_7}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={6} className="mt-3">
                    <Bluecard
                    heading={blueCardData.tc_performance_ratio}
                    spanText={"%"}
                    text={"TCPR"}
                    image={Solar_8}
                    />
                </Col>
                {/* {blueCardData.map((item) => (
                    <Col xl={6} key={item.id}>
                    <Bluecard
                        heading={item.id}
                        spanText={item.albumId}
                        text={item.title}
                        image={item.thumbnailUrl}
                    />
                    </Col>
                ))} */}
                </Row>
            </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
        </section>
        <section className="mt-lg-5 mt-5">
        <Container fluid>
            <Row>
            <Col lg={6}>
                <Linechart chartData={lineData} />
            </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
        </section>
    </>
    );
}

export default Solarcopy;
```

[image: see the img for code]

Comment: Please provide code as text not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

don't use two useEffect with the same dependency array ([]) due to this your code is executing without waiting.
Instead of that combine logic of two useEffect into one also you can you async/await instead of promises syntax , it will be more readable

Comment: I edited the code above in the text format can you plz write this in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

if u use useeffect with ([]) it will only work in the first load. if you want to make it work second useeffect when isLoading false, use it ([isLoading]) in that case everytime isLoading change the second useEffect will work again.

Answer (score 0):

You do a `fetch` call to an API - this code is **asynchronous**, therefore the other **sync** code won't wait for it and continue running before the data was fetched.

So what you should do it take all the asynchronous code of the `fetch` and put it inside an `async` function that will return your fetched data (as a promise).

**Important:** Where you wrote: `setBlueCardData(dataValues)` - **State updates doesn't happen immediately**, so you won't immediately have the data stored in the state after writing this line. See this [link](https://www.daggala.com/react-state-not-updating-immediately/).

Instead, we have he async funciton that will return the fetched `data` for us so we can use it.

Second, now you can use just one `useEffect`, and inside of it you will call the async function, **And once the `data` was fetched** and the promise was resolved - you'll use it, and do all the mapping you need to do.

And about the `isLoading` state - all you need to do is set it to `true` in the first line of the async function - which means that now we are starting to fetch, and then in the end of the function set it to false.

**Code:**

**Async function:**

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true); //starting to fetch.
    const response = await fetch('http://192.168.18.21:8000/performance/solar-overview');
    const dataValues = await response.json();
    setBlueCardData(dataValues); //Won't update immediately!
    setIsLoading(false);//finished loading.(Won't update immediately too!)
    return dataValues;//returning the data.
  };
```

**The useEffect:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((data) => {
      //This all inside the then() block - which means we finished loading and got the data.
      const arr3 = [];
      const arr4 = [];
      data.pr_hourly.time.map((item) => {
        arr4.push(item.time);
      });
      data.pr_hourly.pr_hourly.map((item) => {
        arr4.push(item.pr_hourly);
      });
      setLineData({ /* .. your code here .. */ });
    });
  }, []);
```

**And the JSX: (put your own JSX here)**

```
  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading Data</p>;
  }
  return <div>Your data is here....</div>;
}
```